# Newton's method - determine accuracy in calculation

Tags: algorithms, numerical-methods

I have almost managed to solve a problem (I think), but I am a bit unsure if my procedure is correct, and my answer is not quite the correct one.  Would appreciate any input!  The problem is as follows:

If Newton's method is used with $f(x) = x^2 - 1$ and $x_0 = 10^{10}$, how many steps are required to obtain the root with accuracy $10^{-8}$.  Solve analytically, not experimentally.  (Hint:  restart Newton's algorithm when you know that $e_n < 1$).

OK.  My solution is as follows:

If we have $x_0 = 10^{10}$, and we find, by using Newton's algorithm, that $x_1 = \frac{x_0}{2}$, and $x_2 = \frac{x_1}{2}$ (I tried this for the first few terms).  Thus, we have that:

$$x_{n+1} = \frac{x_0}{2^n}$$

Using the hint, and knowing that the closest root is $x = 1$, and $e_n = x_n - r$, we want to find the first value value $x_n$ such that $|x_n - 1| < 1$.  So we have $-2 < x_n < 2$.  My next step is therefore:

$$\frac{10^{10}}{2^n} < 2$$.

$$10^{10} < 2^{n+1}$$

Solving this for $n$ yields:

$n > 32,2$.

So we must take $33$ steps to get to this point.

OK, now - again using the hint - we restart Newton's algorithm again.  Set $n = 0$ again, and we now know that $e_0 < 1$.  We have that:

$$e_{n+1} = \frac{e_{n}^2}{2(e_{n} + 1)} < \frac{e_{n}^2}{2}$$

Then:

$$e_1 < \frac{e_{0}^2}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2}, e_2 < \frac{e_{1}^2}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2^3}, e_3 < \frac{e_{2}^2}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2^7}, etc$$.

In general:

$$e_{n} < \frac{1}{2^{2^{n} -1}}$$

We want $e_n < 10^{-8}$, and this is found when $n = 6$.  Thus we need to use a total of $33 + 6 = 39$ steps in total.

According to my book, however, the total number of steps should be $40$.  So am I making a mistake here somwhere?  If someone can see if my procedure is correct, and perhaps spot my mistake, I would be very, very grateful!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since $f$ is convex, you can show that if $x_0>1$ then $x_n \geq 1$ for all $n$.
So we can bound the term $\frac{1}{x_n} \leq 1$. The Newton update for $f$ is $x_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2} (x_n + \frac{1}{x_n})$. So we have the bound $x_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2} x_n + \frac{1}{2}$. Working through the details gives $x_n \leq \frac{1}{2^n} x_0 + \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^n} (x_0-1) + 1$. To estimate the number of iterations to get an error of less than 1. we want to find the smallest $n$ such that $2>\frac{1}{2^n} (x_0-1) + 1$, or equivalently, $n > \log_2 (x_0-1) \approx 33.2$. Hence, using this estimate, it will take (assuming I have made no mistakes) 34 iterations to get within an error of 1.

This is an elaboration on the bound above: Since $x_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2} x_n + \frac{1}{2}$, we have $x_{1} \leq \frac{1}{2} x_0 + \frac{1}{2}$. For the induction step,  suppose $x_n \leq \frac{1}{2^n} x_0 + \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2}$. Then we have $x_{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{2} x_n + \frac{1}{2} \leq \frac{1}{2} (\frac{1}{2^n} x_0 + \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2}) + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} x_0 + \frac{1}{2^{n+1}} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2}$,
hence the formula is true for all $n$.

Summing the geometric series, we have $\frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2}(\frac{1-\frac{1}{2^n}}{1-\frac{1}{2}}) = 1-\frac{1}{2^n}$, which gives $x_n \leq \frac{1}{2^n} x_0 + \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdots + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^n} x_0 + 1-\frac{1}{2^n} = \frac{1}{2^n} (x_0-1) + 1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot!  This is most likely a correct approach here.  Can I just ask one question?  I don't quite see how you get that $\frac{1}{2^n}x_0 + \frac{1}{2^n} + \cdot \cdot \cdot + \frac{1}{2} = \frac{1}{2^n}(x_0 - 1) + 1$.  I would be very grateful if you could show how you get this.  Other than that, I understand everything in your reasoning.  Thanks again!

Comment: See the additions above...

Comment: Thank you very much!  This was really helpful! :)

Answer (score 2):

Your equations $x_1=x_0/2$ and $x_2=x_1/2$ are incorrect. Applying Newton's method to $f(x)=x^2-1$ yields

$$x_{n+1}=x_n-\frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)}=x_n-\frac{x_n^2-1}{2x_n}=x_n-\frac{x_n}2+\frac1{2x_n}=\frac{x_n}2+\frac1{2x_n}\ne\frac{x_n}2\;.$$

Comment: Ah.  Thanks a lot. Yeah, I only solved it on my calculator, and since the answers appeared to be halved every time, I assumed this would be correct.  I should have definitely been more careful here!

Comment: Hm, even when I try to solve this equation, I still get $n = 33$ steps in my first calculation :(

Comment: @Kristian: Sorry, there was a sign error; I've corrected it.

Comment: Thanks.  I have trouble finding a general term involving only $x_n$ and $x_0$ here though.  I suppose I could just run this through my Newton algorithm in MatLab, but I kinda feel like I'm cheating if I do it. . .

Comment: @Kristian: I'm afraid I don't understand what you mean by "restarting" the algorithm. If I just apply it to $10^{10}$, I get within $10^{-8}$ of $1$ after $37$ steps.

Comment: Joriki:  What I mean is that I start the iterations with $x_0$ again - only this time I choose to look at the error magnitude.  When combined with copper.hat's approach below, we get the correct answer of 40 iterations in total.

Comment: @Kristian: I see. By the way, you don't have to ping me under my own answer since I get notified of any comments under it anyway; but if you do want to ping someone (under a post that isn't theirs), you need to put an @ in front of the user name.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the tip!  I wasn't aware of the use of @.  I will remember this from now on :)

Comment: @Kristian: You're welcome. And you were right to switch the accepted answer.

Comment: @Jorki:  Yeah, I felt a bit guilty after having already marked your answer as the correct one, but I guess it is the right thing to do.  But I really appreciate your efforts too.  Thank you very much!

Comment: Sorry, didn't mean to edge in. The 'restart' is presumably to switch the analysis from the so-called linear convergence to the so-called quadratic convergence.

Comment: @copper.hat:  Yes, I also assumed so.

Comment: @Kristian: What threw me off was that the hint said to "restart Newton's algorithm", not to restart its analysis. If I understand correctly now, the idea is to apply Newton's algorithm in the usual way for $40$ steps and apply two different kinds of analysis to these steps.

Comment: @joriki:  Yes, the problem was phrased somewhat awkwardly.